# AutoCompleteTextView loads results slowly

Tags: android, android-sqlite, autocompletetextview

My sqlite database has about 82,000 entries in it and I want to be able to dynamically load suggestions quickly using android's AutoCompleteTextView. I've tried increasing the threshold, but there is still a noticeable delay between entering text and the AutoCompleteTextView updating the suggestions list dynamically. What steps can I take to optimize this process?

Comment: Some code could be useful...

Comment: I agree with @Andrew, some code or maybe the SQL you use to select on the table will be helpful, also, a table of `82,000` entries may be too big in sqlite if you have to query on the table frequently.

Comment: Is your database properly indexed?